# Video.js seeking is off by about 5-10 seconds on Android devices

Tags: android, html5-video, video.js

The subject pretty much sums it up.  We have a custom player built on top of Video.js, with a "chapters" menu that allows users to jump to particular parts of a video using the Video.js api, aka:

```
video.currentTime(newValue)
```

This works great on most devices (with a discrepancy of just about 1/2 a second or less), except on Android (specifically testing on a Galaxy S5) it tends to result in the video jumping 5 - 10 seconds earlier into the video than specified i.e. if I do video.currentTime(30) the video starts playing at 24 seconds.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately on most Android devices the video jumps to the next or previous keyframe. Try to convert the video with `ffmpeg` using `-force_key_frames` option.

Comment: Unfortunately we have hundreds of videos, and re-encoding probably isn't an option just to accommodate < 2% of users.  I am looking into -force_key_frames as a last resort though.  Thanks for the input!  Unless something else surfaces today I will accept this as the answer.